# AndroidViewModel vs passing Application context to ViewModel

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) states the following:

> If the ViewModel needs the Application context, for example to find a system service, it can extend the AndroidViewModel class and have a constructor that receives the Application in the constructor, since Application class extends Context.

Code example:

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
... 
}
```

Two questions:

1. How does the AndroidViewModel helps me if I need to pass `Application` to ViewModel's ctor anyway?
2. And again, if I need to pass `Application`, why do I need AndroidViewModel? I can just use ViewModel and pass it `Application`.

Comment: "How does the AndroidViewModel helps me if I need to pass Application to ViewModel's ctor anyway?" -- you are not passing the `Application` to the `ViewModel` constructor, because you are not invoking the `ViewModel` constructor. A factory is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're providing your own factory, you can pass anything you want to a regular `ViewModel` object, you're correct about that.

However, if you are using the default factories, [the source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:lifecycle/lifecycle-viewmodel/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.java;l=264) shows that the default factories **only** fill in the `Application` instance for you if your ViewModel extend `AndroidViewModel`.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your custom `ViewModel` without extending `AndroidViewModel` and it will be functionally identical.

Only difference is default `ViewModelFactory` checks if `ViewModel` is an instance of `AndroidViewModel` and invokes one-arg constructor passing down `Application` context automatically.